# Type quantifiers in Haskell functions

Tags: haskell, lambda-calculus

Suppose I have two Haskell functions of the following types, with ExplicitForAll activated,

```
f :: forall a. (a -> Int)
g :: forall a. (Int -> a)
```

It seems to me that the type of `g` is isomorphic to `Int -> (forall a. a)`, because for example the type of `g(2)` is `forall a. a`.

However, the type of `f` doesn't look isomorphic to `(forall a. a) -> Int`. `f` is a polymorphic function, it knows what to compute on each input type `a`, in mathematics I guess it would rather be a family of functions ; but I don't think it can handle a single argument that has all types.

Is it a rule of typed lambda calculus that type quantifiers distribute on functions target types, but not on functions source types ?

Does the type `(forall a. a) -> Int` exist in Haskell, possibly restrained to a type class `(forall a. SomeClass a => a) -> Int` ? Is it useful ?

Comment: No, they are not isomorphic. What makes you think so?

Comment: If you happen to be familiar with category theory, `f :: forall a. F a -> G a` can be seen as a family of functions which is _natural_ on `a`: it is a natural transformation `F->G` (provided `F,G` are functors, as in this case).

Comment: @n.m. Isn't `g(2) :: forall a. a` a sufficient reason ?

Comment: @chi Indeed, my question originates from natural transformations, which is why I spoke of a family of functions. Do you know if typed lambda calculus has rules for distributing the type quantifiers when `F` or `G` is a constant functor ?

Comment: Type quantifers can be swapped with arrows as in logic: the proposition `p -> forall a. q(a)` is equivalent to `forall a. p -> q(a)` provided `p` does not depend on `a`. If Haskell had existential types, we would have the isomorphism `(forall a. p(a) -> q) ~ ((exists a. p(a)) -> q)`. It commutes with products too `(forall a. p a, forall a. q a) ~ forall a. (p a, q a)`. On sums it's trickier.

Comment: Hmm sorry my mistake, they probably are.

Comment: By the way, just because two types are isomorphic, GHC does not have to identify them. (GHC does perform "hoisting" on `p -> forall a. q(a)`, but the others isos I mentioned are not automatically done, even because they require impredicative polymorphism which is broken at the moment in GHC).

Comment: @chi Perfect, I hadn't thought of using Curry-Howard to interpret functions as implications. If you rewrite that as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2):

`weird :: (forall a. a) -> Int` is unnecessarily specific.

`undefined` is the only value that has type `forall a. a`, so the definiton would have to be `weird _ = someInteger`, which is just a more restrictive version of `const`.

Comment: How about with a typeclass constraint `(forall a. SomeClass a => a) -> Int` ?

Comment: @V.Semeria In such case, it may be possible to find a defined argument. E.g. if `SomeClass = Num`, then `42 :: Num a => a` is a valid argument.

Answer (score 2):

A `∀ a .` is basically just an extra implicit argument, or rather, a specification of how type-constraints pertaining to that argument should be handled. For instance,

```
f :: ∀ a . Show a => (a -> Int)
g :: ∀ a . Show a => (Int -> a)
```

are in essence functions of two arguments,

```
f' :: ShowDictionary a -> a -> Int
g' :: ShowDictionary a -> Int -> a
```

or even dumber,

```
type GenericReference = Ptr Foreign.C.Types.Void -- this doesn't actually exist

f'' :: (GenericReference -> String) -> GenericReference -> Int
g'' :: (GenericReference -> String) -> Int -> GenericReference
```

Now, these are just monomorphic (or weak-dynamic typed) functions. We can clearly use `flip` on them to obtain

```
f''' :: GenericReference -> (GenericReference -> String) -> Int
g''' :: Int -> (GenericReference -> String) -> GenericReference
```

The latter can simply be evaluated partially with any `Int` argument, hence `g` is indeed equivalent to `γ :: Int -> (∀ a . Show a => Int -> a)`.

With `f'''`, applying it to some void-pointered argument would be a recipe to disaster, since there's no way for the type system to ensure that the actually passed type matches the one the `Show` function is prepared to handle.

Comment: Thanks for explaining how GHC implements it behind the scenes. Do you know if this is a theoretical rule of typed lambda calculus too ?

Comment: Yeah, I think in System F it you'd have expressions something like `Λ a . (λ (n:a) . X)` which kind of express the same thing, but I've never really read into that.

Comment: The issue of constraints and type quantification are disjoint - a constraint can appear in a position not immediately to the right of a quantifier, e.g. `forall a . (C a => a) -> X` vs. `forall a . C a => a -> X`; even `(D => X) -> Z` is a valid type. Both are implemented as function arguments in the core representation, but that is the case for quantified type variables for a deeply primitive reason about the type system (the formal semantics of System F omega), whereas for constraints it is simply an implementation detail.

Comment: @user2407038: sounds good. I'd love to see it explained in proper detail, how about adding an answer?

Answer (score 0):

This is a copy of Chi's comment above, it explains the theoretical part by interpreting functions as logical implications (Curry-Howard correspondence) :

> Type quantifers can be swapped with arrows as in logic: the
>   proposition `p -> forall a. q(a)` is equivalent to `forall a. p -> q(a)`
>   provided `p` does not depend on `a`. If Haskell had existential types, we
>   would have the isomorphism `(forall a. p(a) -> q) ~ ((exists a. p(a))
>   -> q)`. It commutes with products too `(forall a. p a, forall a. q a) ~ forall a. (p a, q a)`. On sums it's trickier.

I also link the specs of [RankNTypes](https://prime.haskell.org/wiki/RankNTypes). It does enforce the rules of "floating out" type quantifiers and defines the type `(forall a. SomeClass a => a) -> Int`.